# Does the LHS implies the RHS?

Tags: logic

$\forall y~[ \exists x~[ P(x) \land {L(x,y)} ]] \colon \exists x~[P(x) \land {∀y~[L(x,y)]}]$

Let $L(x,y) := x$ loves $y ; P(x) := x$ eats pizza

I understand LHS as: Everyone is loved by someone and that particular someone eats pizza and
RHS as: There is someone who eats pizza and loves everyone. Is it correct that LHS implies RHS?

Comment: "and that particular someone eats pizza" Nitpick: In my language I wouldn't say that there is "one particular person" who loves y; y may be loved by multiple people but the is at least one person who loves him who eats pizza.... It's a minor nitpick and maybe isn't significant, but it stuck out to me.

Comment: LHS does not imply RHS.  It's true everybody is loved by someone who eats pizza, but it need not be the same person for everone.

Comment: Suppose Sam is loved by Michael who eats pizza, and Bill is loved by Doris who eats pizza.  But Dorris doesn't love Sam and Michael doesn't love Bill.  And to tie this off let's assume Michael and Doris love each other. (And Bill and Sam don't eat pizza and don't love anyone).  LHS is true; RHS is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true.

Suppose there are four people, Adam, Brenda, Charlie and Darya, such that:

- Adam, Brenda and Charlie eat pizza, but Darya does not;
- Adam likes Brenda and Charlie, but not Darya; and
- Brenda likes Adam and Darya, but not Charlie; and
- Charlie doesn't like anyone.

Then everyone is liked by someone who eats pizza, so $\forall y \exists x [P(x) \wedge L(x,y)]$ is satisfied.

However, there is not someone who eats pizza and loves everyone, since Adam doesn't like Darya, Brenda doesn't like Charlie, and Charlie doesn't like anyone (and Darya doesn't eat pizza). So $\exists x[ P(x) \wedge \forall y\ L(x,y)]$ is not satisfied.

---

*P.S.* A counterexample can be constructed with only three people, but it's easier to intuit with four, since a three-person example requires talking about people liking or not liking themselves.

---

*P.P.S.* This is an instance of **quantifier alternation**, since the second formula is equivalent to $\exists x \forall y [P(x) \wedge L(x,y)]$. The general principle at work is that, for any formula $\varphi(x,y)$, it is always true that the implication $\exists y \forall x\ \varphi(x,y) \to \forall x \exists y\ \varphi(x,y)$ is true, but the converse is often false.

Comment: Very useful! Thanks!